# PowerShell command metadata

Tags: windows, powershell, metadata

I'm a PowerShell neophyte. I understand that when one runs a PowerShell command, it sends a stream of objects as an output.

For example:

```
PS C:\Users\JGodse\scripts> Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Product


IdentifyingNumber : {90150000-008C-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
Name              : Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component
Vendor            : Microsoft Corporation
Version           : 15.0.4867.1003
Caption           : Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component

IdentifyingNumber : {90150000-008C-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}
Name              : Office 15 Click-to-Run Localization Component
Vendor            : Microsoft Corporation
Version           : 15.0.4867.1003 
Caption           : Office 15 Click-to-Run Localization Component

IdentifyingNumber : {90150000-008F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}
Name              : Office 15 Click-to-Run Licensing Component
Vendor            : Microsoft Corporation
Version           : 15.0.4867.1003
Caption           : Office 15 Click-to-Run Licensing Component


....... (and many more such objects)......
```

The objects have the properties (IdentifyingNumber, Name, Vendor, Version, Caption). From this I can pipe the objects to something like this to select the Name:

```
PS C:\Users\JGodse\scripts> Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Product | select name

name
----
Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component
Office 15 Click-to-Run Localization Component
Office 15 Click-to-Run Licensing Component
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
```

Is there a way to get a list of attribute names of the objects returned by a command without running the command and visually parsing the output? Perhaps a command like a mythical Get-Attributes:

```
PS C:\> Get-Attributes Get-WmiObject

attributes
----------
IdentifyingNumber, Name, Vendor, Version, Caption
```

Comment: You're looking for [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx).

Comment: Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Product | select -first 1 | Get-Member | ?{ $_.MemberType -eq 'Property' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmdlet you are looking for is get-member, however it will get you the properties available on an object, not the ones that could result from a cmdlet.  This is because depending on which arguments you provide you will get objects back with different results.  (for example get-wmiobject returns different objects for different classes).  You would use it something like below.

`Get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | Get-member`

That will get you a list of all properties and methods available to the object representing the computers win32_operatingsystem WMI class.  Link below has additional information and examples.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx

Comment: In Ruby, I used to do (myObject.methods - Object.methods), and that would yield the relevant methods available on that object. You have given me the effective equivalent of myObject.methods. Is there a way to get rid of the largely irrelevant methods?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of, been a while since I did any Ruby but Object.methods represents a generic collection of methods available to any object right?  if so there really isn't an analog in powershell/.NET as far as I am aware, the methods available to system.object are pretty limited(only 4 of them) so there's not really a need to filter them out.  you could add a `| Where-object {$_.Definition -notlike "*system.object*"}` to remove the methods that inherit from system.object but that's only going to trim 4 methods off of your result.

Comment: `Get-Member -Type Method` should suffice.

Comment: That would give you just the methods on the object but would not show only unique methods as the ruby code referenced would

Comment: I'm aware of that. It will usually give you the relevant methods of the object, though.